# Salesforce reports filter limit

Tags: salesforce

I am tring to build reports in salesforce which need around 30 filters to be applied. Salesforce has a limit of 20 filters as per first row of this page - 
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_analytics_per_edition.htm&language=en_US

Apart from writing these reports in apex/visulforce from scratch, is there any other alternative to workaround this limit?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: 30 filters seems excessive.  It is literally searching for a 1 in a million record.  My best recommendation is optimisation.  Can you reduce the complexity DPLL style and reduce the complexity of what is probably a CNF series of statments.

Comment: Thank you for the input. You are right. Basically the issue was with 'in' clause. This was optimized and the filters were reduced well below 20